# Why do we write /usr/bin/env instead of env

Tags: shebang

I know why `env python` is "better" than `usr/bin/python` and why we thus write the shebang with env.

But why don't we simply write `#!env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python` ?

And why does the first option work at all? I was really surprised when I tried it.

Comment: What if `/usr/bin/` isn’t in `$PATH`?

Comment: Okay that's definitely a problem I did not think about.

But why does `#!env python` work, and `#!python` doesn't?

Comment: I don’t know. `#!env python` doesn’t work for me. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77512/why-not-use-pathless-shebangs) seems related.